# Select/deselect checkboxes from all pages using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I am new in Angular and want to select or deselect all checkboxes from all pages. I have a master checkbox but it select and deselect only the current displayed page. I want to add a link(an option) which will help me, by clicking on it one time I want to select all checkboxes from the first to the last page.

html look like:

```
<span ng-click="selectAll()" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span class="xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx xx-xx"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;select/deselect all
</span>
```

How can I implement my function `selectAll()` to get all items of all my pages?

```
$scope.selectAll = function () {/* some code */};
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anythings ?

Comment: Question is too broad without a lot more detail about how *"all my pages"* works and the data model these checkboxes are bound to. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: it so that i have 100 pages sometimes more than 100. and i don't want to click to next pages to select all items in the current pages until the 100 pages. so i decide to add an option which help me to select and deselect all without go to others pages. to get all items of all page i do this: $scope.numberOfItems = allPage.records; tableState.pagination.numberOfPages = allPage.total;

Comment: Just a quick comment: **I don't think that's the best design decision**. It's not necessarily a good idea to let the user select things they cannot see, especially if it's another 99 pages worth. By default, as a user, I would assume `select all` means `select all for the current page`.